# How to retrieve and modify with PHP Domdocument the link (all "href" attribute) having "red text" on this Wikipedia infobox Page?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to retrieve and modify the link of red text URLs (**including:** *AutoNavi, UCWeb* and *AGTech Holdings Limited*) at the infobox level here:

[image]

My code below allows me to replace via **DomDocument**, all the `href` attributes containing `/wiki/` in all the `a` tags of the Document or the Web Page by the character string: `$urlSearch = BASE_PATH."search.php?term=$term&type=sites"` with `str_ireplace`:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$parser = new DOMDocument();
$parser->loadHTMLFile("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alibaba_Group");
$get_a_tags = $parser->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($get_a_tags as $get_a_tag) {
                if (stripos($get_a_tag->getAttribute('href'), "/wiki/") !== false || stripos($get_a_tag->getAttribute('href'), "#") !== false) {
                    $get_href_in_a_infobox = $get_a_tag->getAttribute('href');
                    $term = $get_a_tag->nodeValue;
                    $urlSearch = BASE_PATH."search.php?term=$term&type=sites";
                    // var_dump($urlSearch."<br><br>");
                    $wikipediaInfoboxTable = str_ireplace($get_href_in_a_infobox, $urlSearch, $wikipediaInfoboxTable);
                }
            }
```

**My code above works fine.**

**BUT,** the problem is that when I reproduce the same thing to retrieve the URLs containing in their href, the string `/w/index.php?` or even `redlink=1` by simply doing: `if (stripos ($get_a_tag->getAttribute('href'), "/w/index.php?") !== false || stripos($get_a_tag->getAttribute('href'), "redlink=1") !== false)`, **I don't notice any changes like this was successful in the previous code for the CSS class containing the word** `/wiki/` **change.**

How to successfully modify the link (`href` attribute) of all a tags having CSS class `new`???

In other words, how can I successfully modify, as I did in my code above, the links (`href` attribute) containing the character strings `/w/index.php?` and `redlink=1` ???

I really need your help.

Comment: What does `$wikipediaInfoboxTable` actually contain here? And why are you even doing string replacing in some string variable to begin with - instead of actually working with the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

`$wikipediaInfoboxTable` actually contains the table of infobox. What suggestions do you give me to work directly in the DOM as you say ???

So, how do I replace the `href` in my code case without using the `str_ireplace`???